# How can I monitor the value of some scope variables for changes?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code in my appController. The code sets the value of $scope.cursorWait to true when there's an HTTP in progress:

```
    $scope.$on('cfpLoadingBar:started', function (event, data) {
        $scope.cursorWait = true;
    });

    $scope.$on('cfpLoadingBar:completed', function (event, data) {
        $scope.cursorWait = false;
    });
```

I also have this in my connect service. The functions get called when the internet is disconnected:

```
isConnectedHandler = (): void => {
    var self = this;
    self.$rootScope.connected = true;
    self.$rootScope.disconnected = false;
    self.connectMessage = null;
    self.minutes = 0;
}

isNotConnectedHandler = (): void => {
    var retry = 0;
    var self = this;
    self.$rootScope.connected = false;
    self.$rootScope.disconnected = true;
```

How could I monitor the value of $rootScope.disconnected and cursorWait to then set the value of a rootScope variable waiting to true if either $rootScope.disconnected or cursorWait were true?

Comment: you can use `$scope.$watch('variable',function())` for this

Comment: But in this case I need to watch more than one variable?  Can you give an example, maybe in an answer so I can accept if you know of a way for watch to monitor more than one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your controller has several ViewModels it would like to monitor, let's say `cursorWait` and `connected` for example. In this case, Angular provide you with the `watchGroup` ability. This way you can monitor several variables and in the case one of them change, you may react accordingaly.

***Sample Code*** (Using Typescript for demonstration)

```
$scope.$watchGroup([()=> { return this.cursorWait }, ()=> { return this.connected}], 
(oldValues, newValues)=> {

      /* The callback gets an array of `oldValues` and an array of `newValues`, 
         the index according to the variables you were watching */
    });
```

For more information, refer to Angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).